# Need reference to a Working example of Ontology

Tags: java, owl, ontology

I got introduced to OWL [here](http://www.w3schools.com/rdf/rdf_owl.asp) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-guide/). And also seen few examples like...
http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl

How should I run this example? Are there any tools to run these OWL files?

Is there any blog/site to see a working example of Ontology? An example to say..."This is the difference that Ontology makes..." kind of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I found on the web: [a Java framework for building Semantic Web applications](http://jena.sourceforge.net/). Looks like it can read/process OWL formatted ontologies.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, please also consider using the [Manchester OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) - it is extremely powerful and very close to syntax of owl. This, in combination with any number of reasoners, will allow you to leverage your ontology into an application.

The website describing the api also has an extensive set of tutorials that will get you up and running in no time!